# display top space (header) when editing a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

Suddenly Word doesn't display anymore the page top margin space when editing a document:
[image]
I need to do `Insert > Header > Modify` to make it displayed again:
[image]
How can I restore the default display behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the picture below, scroll your mouse to the top of a page until you see the icon in the picture. Once you see that icon, double click your mouse. This will display the the header/footer white space. Exit out of Word and then re-open Word. This should have solved the problem.

[image]